# How do I deploy my firebase functions into a specific region?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.sendChatMsgNotification = functions.region('europe-west1')
firestore
  .document('chats/{idChat}/messages/{idMessage}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    console.log('----------------start function--------------------')
```

I am trying to deploy my Firebase cloud function into europe-west1 region because the default is us-central1, but I am always getting errors.

Yes, I have already tried to follow the official documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#android. I just have no idea how to apply it correctly. I have tried many times.

If someone can just show me how to apply the correct way using my code above, would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Are you missing a dot (.) after the region and before `firestore`?

Comment: Oh it was really just the dot (.) after all! How have I not noticed this all the time. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before

```
exports.sendChatMsgNotification = functions.region('europe-west1')
firestore
```

After (working)

```
exports.sendChatMsgNotification = functions.region('europe-west1').
firestore
```

I was only missing a dot (.) before "firestore". Thanks @Jason Berryman for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

For v2:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade#set_runtime_options

```
import {onDocumentCreated} from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";
import {setGlobalOptions} from "firebase-functions/v2";
// locate all functions closest to users
setGlobalOptions({region: "us-west2"});
export const userCreated =
  onDocumentCreated("users/{userId}", (event) => { ... });
```